# Strange output on using scanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

```
#include <cstdio>  

int main()  
{  
    int i;
    printf("%d", scanf("%d", &i));
}
```

Whatever number i input, i get the output:

```
1
```

Why is it so?

Comment: `<cstdio>` is a C Standard header.

Comment: @DeadMG- You are being ridiculous. `Each header from the C Standard Library is included in the C++ Standard Library under a different name, generated by removing the .h, and adding a 'c' at the start`. The question is both C and C++ specific.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On success, the [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) function

> returns the number of items successfully read.

This count can match the expected number of readings or fewer, even zero, if a matching failure happens.
In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully read, [EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/EOF/) is returned.

Try this as well:

`printf("%d",scanf("%d%d",&i,&i));`

Comment: The OP probably wants the number entered, which will be in 'i' after scanf returns.

Comment: Nope, i feel he does not know what `scanf` exactly returns.

Answer (score 4):

You output the result of [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/), which is not the number you enter, but the number of items that are successfully read. The number you enter is stored in i. To output it you would have to write an additional line:

```
#include <cstdio>  

int main()  
{  
   int i;
   if (scanf("%d",&i) == 1)
       printf("%d", i);
}
```

Comment: Too much unvalidated input in S.O. questions, don't want it in answers too! - *much* better to say `if (scanf("%d", &i) == 1) printf("%d\n", i);`

Comment: Edited according to your suggestions.

Comment: Well, I better give you a +1 then ;-).  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` returns the number of items read when it succeeds. Here its reading only one number hence the output is 1 every time regardless of the number.